# Task Runner for WebPack not finding any modules

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I had to reinstall Visual Studio 2019 and after doing so, Task Runner for webpack is unable to find *any* of my modules for my project. For example:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-property-decorator'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-select'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'inversify'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'

Webpack is creating the javascript output file however. My webpack configuration file has not changed. I did update the version of node I was using. Other than that, everything is the same and was working fine before reinstalling.

Typescript server is compiling on save as expected and js files are being generated.

My question is weather or not this is a babel issue, taskrunner issue, typescript issue or webpack issue. I'm not totally clear on what is failing to compile these modules. All my packages are found in the node_modules folder and a .bin folder exists in there as well.

I would appreciate any advice on how to track this down.

Comment: did you try ctrl + shift+ p TS server restart? Also is tsconfig existing in project root?

Comment: Yes, typescript server is compiling on save as expected. tsconfig also exists in root.